# Wordpress php function wp_upload_dir() derived path I apply in functions.php is being overridden

Tags: php, wordpress, path, overriding

Putting a basic js arcade game in a single post on WP website with Newspaper theme - hosted locally by WAAMP on my laptop. In functions.php the javascript files links are added to the footer. The `wp_upload_dir()` derived path I use for those files is being over ridden somewhere and results in GET 404 (not found) error.

This path is overridden:

Upload URL: http://localhost/oka-digital/wp-content/uploads

By this path somehow:

GET http://localhost/arcade-js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

How do I stop the override?

Here is the function.php code:

```
/ Single post addition of javascript for arcade game project
function wpb_hook_javascript_footer() {
    if (is_single ('317')) {

    // Get the upload directory information
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    // Access specific information
    $upload_base_url = $upload_dir['baseurl']; // URL to the uploads directory
    $upload_path = $upload_dir['path'];         // Server path to the uploads directory
?>
        <script src="<?php $upload_base_url ?>/arcade-js/resources.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php $upload_base_url ?>/arcade-js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php $upload_base_url ?>/arcade-js/engine.js"></script>
<?php
}
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_javascript_footer');
```

Errors:

localhost/:1460     GET http://localhost/arcade-js/resources.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1461     GET http://localhost/arcade-js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1462     GET http://localhost/arcade-js/engine.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use

```
$upload_base_url = wp_get_upload_dir()["basedir"];
```

however you are already doing that meaning you have set the uploades directory earlier outside the scope of the code you supplied.

More information can be found in the WordPress documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_upload_dir/)

your code is getting the top level url not the uploads directory.

Comment: Yeah I think its the WP theme probably over riding my function. Will look at wp_enqueue_script() to see if that approach works. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I had to abandon the `wp_upload_dir()` approach.

This worked:

In `functions.php`:

Used a conditional to target the specific post by i.d.
Used `wp_enqueue_script`, `get_template_directory_uri()` to load js files.
Created an array of relative paths to images using `get_template_directory_uri()`.
Made this array accessible to the js files using `wp_localize_script`. Set post relative image paths in the javascript files using this array.